# Error 1044 <42000>: Access denied for user ''@' localhost' to database

Tags: mysql-error-1044

I started learning PHP since last few days and this is where I'm stuck at.

When I try to type `CREATE DATABASE blog;` in shell, this is the error I get

> 'Error 1044 <42000>: Access denied for user ''@' localhost' to
>   database'

How do I fix this?

I found titles to this error but those answer were complicated for me to understand.

Comment: Please give an update with a closer description of what you are doing. With what user are you logged in? At which point do you try to create the database?

Comment: I'm watching the tutorial and following exactly what he's been doing.

I first opened the shell, then enter 'mysql' and enter.

After that I tried to check databases, so I did 'SHOW DATABASES' and it did showed but there was 8 databases but it shows only 2 in shell. It didn't even showed the one I did manually in phpmyadmin.

Then I tried to create a new database with 'CREATE DATABASE blog;' command. 

Sorry if I'm confusing you with my bad english

Comment: Is the tutorial online? Seems like you log in with the wrong user...

Comment: wow. Thank you so much for the hint, after reading your comment instead of just entering 'mysql', I tried to enter 'mysql -u root -p'  and it did fix my problem. Thank you so much bro :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entering mysql without a special user is not working. Or better to say: You enter the database, but the user you use then, has nearly no rights/priviliges. So in the beginning you need to login with your root account with `mysql -u root -p`.
Then you can create your databases and work with them.

**Hint 1:** Never work with the root user in a productive system, but create an user, that just has access to one database. 
**Hint 2:** Change the password of the root user as soon as possible with `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('mein_pwd') WHERE user='root';` when you're in the database.

Comment: Thanks bro.

Is hint 2 same as 'SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = pass('password');' ?

Comment: I guess yes, but my hint is more in the syntax of MySQL